# Why didn't the Russian- and every other nuclear capable country- shut down their nukes?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In Arrow season 4 episode 21, all of the world's nukes were activated- including Russia's. So at this point, it was obvious they were being hacked. So why didn't they simply shut them down, and why wasn't there more of a world collaboration (in fact I don't think there was any for that matter) for what was probably the highest possible state of emergency? Am I wrong in assuming that at the very least, there aren't any specialist government programmers like Felicity who could've made an effort in stopping Havenrock from being nuked?

Comment: [The Russians can't.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yfXgu37iyI)

Comment: And I would not be surprised if the policy is that, if one country is going to launch its missiles, we're going to launch ours.

Comment: [Nuclear War 101, 102, 103](https://gist.github.com/benders/141611)

Answer (score 3):

### Why couldn't the missile operators just stop the launch?

The missiles weren't *being* hacked, they *were* hacked; past tense. The operators had already lost control of their command systems. One of the Russian soldiers says this in the very first scene:

> **Soldier:** At zero-three-sixteen, silos one through four rebooted and are now powering up to launch sequence.
>
> **Commander:** What do you mean, "rebooted"?
>
> **Soldier:** I've been locked out of the system...
>
> <sup>*Arrow* Season 4 Episode 21: "Monument Point"</sup>

This is kind of the point of Rubicon, actually; if any country could circumvent it from their missile bases, it would rather undermine the intended purpose:

> **Lyla:** [Rubicon is a] ballistic launch override protocol designed to prevent any country, even our own, from firing a nuclear missile.
>
> <sup>*Arrow* Season 4 Episode 20: "Genesis"</sup>

### Why wasn't there more international response?

Well, we don't really know *what* was going on outside of Star City; maybe there was some concerted international effort to stop the nukes. It seems unlikely it would have succeeded, though; Lyla herself says:

> **Lyla:** Rubicon is a failsafe against nuclear Armageddon. ARGUS designed it to be 100% unhackable.
>
> <sup>*Arrow* Season 4 Episode 21: "Monument Point"</sup>

Even Felicity and Noah, who are basically wizards, only manage to (almost) stop them by using hyper-advanced, *experimental* computer hardware.

Comment: True, but you can still manually remove the main source of power- .e.g. if someone takes control of my computer and the shutdown button doesn't work, I can still pull out the plug

Comment: @Logan545 Again, if Rubicon were easy to subvert then it would be pointless. I don't know much about how missile command centers work, but I know that they're designed to be *highly* tamper resistant

Comment: @JasonBaker: I think I agree with everything you said, except for the first sentence of the above comment.  If Rubicon was designed to prevent countries from firing nuclear missiles, then [other] actions taken to disable missiles, or otherwise prevent their launch and/or detonation, do not constitute a subversion the goals of Rubicon.

Answer (score 0):

Because that would not have made a good show... Sadly a lot of the time the reason why there are flaws in plots such as this is because the  shows/movies are written to be action filled cliffhangers not for logic and what would happen in real life...